# react-select, on selecting option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

I'm using the react-select dropdown for my project. When I tried to select an option from the dropdown and check the dropdown all the option background colors turned blue. When I inspect, all options have the class name react-select-option-is-selected.

I need the background color applied to only the selected option, not all the options
[image]

```js
import Select from 'react-select';
const savedLists = [
    {
        "__typename": "List",
        "key": "3232",
        "name": "Saved List A"
    },
    {
        "__typename": "List",
        "key": "323",
        "name": "rwecrrrcrcsas"
    },  
]
const modifiedSavedList = savedLists.map(({ name: label, ...rest }) => ({
    label, ...rest
  }));

  const onChangeHandler = (selectedDestination) => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const checkedProductsIds = items.filter((e, i) => checkedList.some(j => i == j)).map(obj => (obj.uid));
    const sourceUID = searchParams.get('uid');
    SetOptionSelected(selectedDestination.name)
    copyitmes(sourceUID, selectedDestination, checkedProductsIds)
  }
```

```
<Select
 className="itemListDropdown"
 classNamePrefix="react-select"
 options={modifiedSavedList}
 isSearchable={false}
 placeholder={<div>Copy to</div>}
 components={{ IndicatorSeparator: () => null }}
 onChange={onChangeHandler}
 />
```

```
.itemListDropdown {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 71%;
    height: 36px;
    color: $color-medium-grey !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-left: auto;

    .react-select__control {
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid $color-medium-grey;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 12px;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .react-select__value-container {
        height: $input-box-min-height;
        align-content: center;
    }

    .react-select__value-container,
    .react-select__menu,
    .react-select__input-container,
    .react-select__menu-list {
        padding: unset;
        margin: unset;
    }

    .react-select__menu {
        box-shadow: unset;
    }

    .react-select__option--is-selected {
        background-color: $select-menu-background-hover;
        color: $color-white;
    }

    .react-select__control--menu-is-open {
        border-color: $color-medium-grey !important;
        border-style: solid !important;
        border-width: 2px 2px 1px 2px !important;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    }

    .react-select__placeholder,
    .react-select__indicator {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should share your code. It'd help to understand what is going on with your setup.

Comment: It would be easy to understand the issue if you can create a runnable sample and share the link, you can use codesandbox / stackblitz / w/e works for you  (add code, save and share the link)

Comment: @NickVu, Will share now. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @KcH, I cannot create runnable sample because the code is integrated with other components

Comment: you can always create a sample one reproducing the issue ..

Comment: @NickVu , can you please check and help me out

Comment: @KcH, actually i don't know how to do that. sorry

Comment: @KiranKumarV don't be sorry , the problem is it takes assumptions for e.g. what is causing the style to have background in first place, is it `className="itemListDropdown"` ?

Comment: @KcH actually even if remove the className and classPrefix still it is selecing all options in the background

Comment: A *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live would be handy here then.

Comment: @DrewReese https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-afp6gb?embed=1&file=App.js

Comment: @DrewReese https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-easley-oeuvmi

Comment: @NickVu https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-easley-oeuvmi

Answer (score 1):

This is because you provide a wrong structure of options to your react select.
Each option should have value and label. Since you provide only label, but not value, react-select can't understand what is selected.

Try to change

```
const modifiedSavedList = savedLists.map(({ name: label, ...rest }) => ({
    label, value: { ...rest }
  }));
```